# dynamically fill ListActivity

Tags: android

There is a thread that fills the db and I am trying to make my ListActivity to grow dynamically according to the entries in the db. By dynamically I mean to grow in real time while the db is filling.

What is the best way to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.androidguys.com/2009/10/21/tutorial-autogrowing-listview/ this is just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need is ListView with an adapter which will extend `android.widget.CursorAdapter`.